# How to separate collapse using Bootstrap Accordion in reusable Razor component?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, bootstrap-5

I am using the Accordion from bootstrap to show and hide information. In here, information is stored. The information is different depending on each accordion but the setup is the same.

Because I have multiple accordions I have turned this in a reusable component using Razor (Blazor).

My issue right now is that I want to be able to have every accordion act independently, meaning when I open one accordion, the other ones stay closed and when I close one accordion, the other ones stay open etc.

The current situation is, because it is a reusable component, when I open/close one component, all the other ones do the same.

Here is my current code:

```
    <div class=@FormListClass>
        @foreach (var trackingFormShareable in TrackingFormShareables)
        {

            <div class="accordion" id="accordion">

                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
                        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne">
                            @trackingFormShareable.TrackingFormName
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                            @foreach (var courseItem in trackingFormShareable.CourseItems)
                            {
                                <CourseItemTrackingDetails ClickedCourseItem='_clickedCourseItem' IsFolded='@(CurrentCourseItemId != null)' TrackingCourseItemShareable=courseItem></CourseItemTrackingDetails>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        }
    </div>
```

Does anyone know how to do this (better)?

Answer (score 0):

Your `<button>` is hard coded to target the same div (`data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne"`). Any time you click the button it's talking to all the components because they have the same id.

Generate a unique string for button attribute `data-bs-target` and div attribute `id`.

> Does anyone know how to do this (better)?

The blazor approach would be to rely on blazor for collapsing the card and not bootstrap. You could move each `<div class="accordion-item">` into it's own component, thus giving it it's own state. The button then uses c# to hide / show it's body.

```
<button class="accordion-button" @onclick="() => _show = !_show" type="button" >
    @trackingFormShareable.TrackingFormName
</button>
...
@if (_show)
{
<div class="accordion-body">
...
</div>
}
@code
{
     private bool _show = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a simple component to encapsulate the accordion functionality and build the collapse/expand functionality into the component.

Here's one way to implement it:

**BootstrapAccordion.razor**

```cs
<div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header">
        <button class="@this.buttonCss" type="button" @onclick=this.ToggleContent>
            @this.Header
        </button>
    </h2>
    @if (hideContent)
    {
        <div class="accordion-collapse collapse show">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                @this.ChildContent
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string? Header { get; set; }
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool DefaultClosed { get; set; }

    private bool hideContent;

    private string buttonCss => this.hideContent ? "accordion-button collapsed" : "accordion-button";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => hideContent = this.DefaultClosed;

    private void ToggleContent()
    =>  hideContent = !hideContent;
}
```

And then a demo page:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<BootstrapAccordion Header="Hello Blazor">
    <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
</BootstrapAccordion>
```